# Advantages of OSM over Google Maps for custom map in app

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, comparison

I wanted to map my city on a private map. I have read about maps and I found that I will need tiles. Looking at available service, could not find one that allows me to host them in my server. Which means I have to comply with their own terms.

So I was left wondering **what is the advantage then, of using OSM over Google Maps**?

Am new to GIS so it might be no brainer question. In that case I apologize

**UPDATE**

So here is what I want basically (Just to give an idea since the idea itself is huge). I take OSM/GM data into my database. I add different stuffs in different locations local to that City and correct them to better accuracy where it is not. Add bus stops, hotels, homes, et al.

Then I make simple app to guide someone to go to place they want. That is the basic of the idea.

Comment: Actually you can host your OSM tiles locally, check out instructions from this source: https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/
When you host tiles locally you can style them whatever you want and choose what data you serve.

Comment: Please add information about what exactly you need. "map my city on a private map" could mean many things and the details will influence our recommendations.

Comment: @underdark I have updated my question. Please let me know if it is still lacking. Also if you can help me edit it with better GIS terms I will appreciate

Comment: @d324223 didn't knew that. Let me check it out

Comment: When you take OSM data and start editing it, you have to comply to the ODbL-license for your data.

Answer (score 1):

I Found an answer here. Thanks @d324223 for pointing out the Link.
It address all my questions (some I ad yet to ask). In case the link goes out of scope, here is the relevant text:

> OpenStreetMap won’t charge you
>
> OpenStreetMap is open data. We won’t charge for it – ever. Our licence
>   says that you can always copy our data for free.
>
> This data is made into the “map tiles” that you show on your site. You
>   can do this yourself. Or you can find a specialist to do it: some will
>   charge for this, some won’t. But OpenStreetMap itself will never
>   charge you for the data. Make the maps suit you
>
> With other map providers, the map looks how the provider wants it to
>   look. You might be able to do a bit of rudimentary recolouring. But
>   it’s still their style of map, not yours.
>
> With OpenStreetMap, you’re in control. Turning the data into tiles can
>   be done any way you like. Want to emphasise cycle routes and play down
>   motorways? No problem. (Most other maps don’t even have cycle routes.)
>   Want to label subway stops but ignore bus stops? Easy. Rich, accurate,
>   up-to-date map data
>
> Most commercial providers just do streets. OpenStreetMap might have
>   “street” in the name, but we do much more. Natural features, bus
>   routes, footpaths and cycleways, administrative boundaries, shops,
>   rivers and canals… you name it.
>
> Commercial providers also only update their data every month, if
>   you’re lucky. New roads and buildings can be missing from their
>   datasets long after they’ve opened. OpenStreetMap data is constantly
>   updated, and you can get those updates every day, every hour or even
>   every minute if you want.
>
> All this is contributed by our volunteers (over 1,000,000 signed up so
>   far, and growing every day) – the people who really know about their
>   area. That’s why OpenStreetMap often shows new developments before any
>   commercial provider. It’s easier than you think
>
> There’s no limit to what you can do with OpenStreetMap. Yet it needn’t
>   take long to get started. You can switch to OSM in under an hour using
>   tools like the easy Leaflet API and MapQuest Open’s free tiles. Read
>   the rest of this site to get started with the possibilities.

Comment: Glad you found answer for your question. What is also worth to notice is that google maps, although offering a lot of very useful services which may suits your needs just fine, once in a while can change it's charges policy. Because of that your map may become inaccessible or useless in case your users hit some excessive number of requests.

Comment: I see. The only advantage for Google maps I see is they work for you so that you can concentrate on other business things. When you grow enough to hit the quotas, they then charge. Its a fair model but I just think its not right for this specific project. Thank you!